# как в Delphi при ctrl + a выделить всю строку в dbgrid

Tags: delphi-7, dbgrid

сделал при нажатии на button выделение всех строк в dbgrid можно ли при сочетании клавиш ctrl + a выделить все строки?

```
function GridSelectAll(Grid: TDBGrid): Longint;
begin
  Result := 0;
  Grid.SelectedRows.Clear;
  with Grid.Datasource.DataSet do
  begin
    First;
    DisableControls;
    try
      while not EOF do
      begin
        Grid.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected := True;
        inc(Result);
        Next;
      end;
    finally
      EnableControls;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.btn13Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GridSelectAll(dbgrd1);
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо зарегистрировать [глобальную горячую клавишу](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/sys_hotkey.html) и в событии вызывать вашу функцию выделения, либо установить форме KeyPreview := True и в событии OnKeyDown обработать нажатую клавишу.

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (ssCtrl in Shift) and (Key = $41) then
    then  GridSelectAll(dbgrd1);
end;
```